# How to make cxgrid row color transparent 

Tags: devexpress

I'm changing grid's row color to red according to my needs and when it gets colored the text is invisible, under backroung color...

How to change the text color or make it transparent ???

```
void __fastcall TfRegular::tvFillOutCustomDrawCell(TcxCustomGridTableView *Sender,
          TcxCanvas *ACanvas, TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo *AViewInfo,
          bool &ADone)
{
    TRect ARec;
    ARec=AViewInfo->Bounds;

        //AViewInfo->GridRecord->DisplayTexts[7]="+" + AViewInfo->GridRecord->DisplayTexts[7];

//  ShowMessage(AViewInfo->GridRecord->Values[13]);
    if (AViewInfo->GridRecord->Values[13]>1) {
        ACanvas->Canvas->Brush->Color = clRed;
        ACanvas->Canvas->Font->Color = clBlack;
        ACanvas->Canvas->Pen->Color = clRed;
        ACanvas->Canvas->FillRect(ARec);
        SetBkMode(ACanvas->Canvas->Handle,TransparentColor);

            //InflateRect(AViewInfo->Bounds,2,2);  
        //ACanvas->DrawTexT("",AViewInfo->Bounds,0);

        ADone=true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was really easy than I thought.

I solved this problem using OnGetContentStyle event.